# validator not working with input type date in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I am a newbe of Laravel 6. I made an app to create meetings.
The user creates a meeting by a form with many inputs and in the controller there is a validator that checks if the inputs are filled in.
Every field works well with the validator except for the two inputs type time ("start" and "end").
When I submit the form and I let one of those fields blank the validator doesn't work correctly because it appears an exception message:

```
InvalidArgumentException Illegal operator and value combination.
```

Furthermore in the tools for developers appears the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I tried changing `required` with `required|date_format:H:i` for both fields but it didn't work as well.
I tried even removing CheckTime that is a custom rule that checks if the end of the meeting be after the beginning but I failed.

**input "start"**

```
            <label for="start" class="col-sm-2">Start Hour:</label>
            @if (old('start') !== null)
                <input type="time" class="form-control col-sm-6" id="start" name="start" value="{{ old('start') }}">
            @elseif (isset($id))
                <input type="time" class="form-control col-sm-6" id="start" name="start" value="{{ $meeting->start_hour }}">
            @else
                <input type="time" class="form-control col-sm-6" value = "{{ old('start') }}" id="start" name="start">
            @endif
```

**input "end"**

```
            <label for="end" class="col-sm-2">End Hour:</label>
            @if (old('end') !== null)
                <input type="time" class="form-control col-sm-6" id="end" name="end" value="{{ old('end') }}">
            @elseif (isset($id))
                <input type="time" class="form-control col-sm-6" id="end" name="end" value="{{ $meeting->end_hour }}">
            @else
                <input type="time" class="form-control col-sm-6" value = "{{ old('end') }}" id="end" name="end">
            @endif
```

**validator:**

```
public function insert_meeting(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'participants' => [ 'required', new CheckParticipantInsert() ], 
        'description' => 'required',
        'room' => [ 'required', new CheckRoomInsert() ],
        'date_meeting' => [ 'required', new CheckDateTime() ],
        'start' => [ 'required', new CheckTime() ],
        'end' => 'required',
    ]);

    $participants_mail = $this->convertIdToName(request('participants'));

    $mail_response = $this->send_mail_create($request, $participants_mail);

    $meeting = new Meeting();

    $participants = request('participants');
    $meeting->id_participants = implode(';', $participants);

    $meeting->description = request('description');
    $meeting->id_room = request('room');
    $meeting->date = request('date_meeting');
    $meeting->start_hour = request('start');
    $meeting->end_hour = request('end');

    $meeting->save();

    if($mail_response) {
        $message_correct = "The meeting has been correctly inserted. The emails to advise the participants have been sent.";
        return redirect()->route('home')->with('success', $message_correct); 
    } else {
        $message_correct = "The meeting has been correctly inserted.";
        $mail_not_sent = "The emails to advise the participants could not be sent";
        return redirect()->route('home')->with('success', $message_correct)->with('mail_not_sent', $mail_not_sent);
    }

}
```

In theory both fields are required so I don't understand why appears an exception error and by the way why the validator doesn't let simply a similar message in the view: `The start field is required` or . `The end field is required` . Is someone able to help me?

Comment: we would need to see what you are doing in your custom rules ... you can look at the stacktrace, it will tell you exactly where the error is caused from

Comment: When the server fails with a 500, it is nice to include the error message, i do not think it has anything to do with validation

Comment: the error is coming from the query builder, but we definitely need to see some of the stack trace

Comment: the validator doesn't return any messages because you have an exception that is thrown by your code, it doesn't make it to the part where the validation can fail and throw a validation exception or validation passed and what you are doing next causes the exception

Comment: Yep the error was caused by my custom rules... because in CheckParticipantInsert and in CheckRoomInsert I made a query with the values "start" and "end" that were null. So now it works adding a checker in both custom rules that returns false if the time values are null.